# NullPointerException while Tomcat Server Shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat

Whenever I am shutdowning the tomcat server i am getting the following exception.

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.publish(FileHandler.java:135)
at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:452)
at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:474)
at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:590)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.log(Jdk14Logger.java:91)
at
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.info(Jdk14Logger.java:162)
at
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol.pause(Http11BaseProtocol.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.pause(Connector.java:1031)
at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:491)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:743)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:601)
```

Someone please help me what i can do to remove this type of error while shutting down.

Comment: What problem is it causing you?

Answer (score 0):

Error code 1 this is `WRITE_FAILURE`.

You need to check permissions for user who run Tomcat.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, i just have checked with the permissions, and its given all rights. however i got this problem randomly not every time.
Please Suggest

Comment: As I understand tomcat is under windows control. I've faced with similar problem with access rights. I've resolved it then replaced permissions to subdirectories. (Right click on Tomcat directory -> Security -> Advanced -> Replace permission .....)